# Grammar when listing question [e.g. we test i) does X cause Y, ii) does a cause b?]

Tags: grammar

I am writing a scientific paper and at the end of the introduction I list the three questions we tackle in the paper. Currently it is written as:

> "Here we address the following three questions: *i)* does A cause B, *ii)* does C cause D, and *iii)* does E cause F?"

Alternatively I could write:

> "Here we address the following three questions: *i)* does A cause B? *ii)* does C cause D? and *iii)* does E cause F?"

Or:

> "Here we address the following three questions: *i)* Does A cause B? *ii)* Does C cause D? And *iii)* does E cause F?"

Would any of these be (more) correct? Is there another more correct alternative?

*Note: I use British English throughout the manuscript. It would be useful to get answers for both American and British English though.*

Comment: There is an argument that, once you start using bulleted lists, normally preferred conventions are left behind, and choice of style is just that. Here, I'd use the three question marks to signal ends of questions; the numbering is adequate to signal beginnings of questions, so the capitalisation is unnecessary (but hardly incorrect). There are previous questions here on punctuating bulleted lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A journal's style sheet will usually address punctuation questions like this. What is reasonable is moot, if the style sheet mandates a particular approach.

I would write instead:

> ...three questions:  Does A cause B? Does C cause D? And does E cause
>   F?

Three separate sentences each ending with a question mark should be sufficient to orient the reader; no need for the Roman-numeral claptrap.

P.S. You can safely ignore  the "rule" that says a sentence should not begin with the word "And".

Comment: Why include "and"?  It sounds better without it in my opinion.